# Error in if (condition) with the arguments dms2deg

Tags: r, file

I´ve download the package celestial in R to convert data from degree minutes seconds to degrees format but an error appear. The data is in Longitude and Latitude in this format 80'13'007.

```
targetCounts$LongitudeDD <- dms2deg(targetCounts$Longitude, sep = "'")
targetCounts$LatitudeDD <- dms2deg(targetCounts$Latitude, sep = "'")

Error in if (any(d < -90 | d > 90) & sign[1] == "d") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(d, -90) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(d, 90) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors


targetCounts$LongitudeDD <- dms2deg(targetCounts$Longitude, sign = "d", sep = "'")

Error in if (any(d < -90 | d > 90) & sign[1] == "d") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(d, -90) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(d, 90) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

There is no blank space in my data, so now I know that is not the problem.

```
> is.na(targetCounts$Longitude)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
[31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
[46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
[61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> str(targetCounts)
'data.frame':   65 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Trip     : int  1638 1638 1638 1638 1638 1638 1639 1639 1639 1639 ...
 $ Lance    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ Fecha    : Factor w/ 54 levels "01/04/2017","02/03/2017",..: 36 38 40 43 
46 48 2 4 7 10 ...
 $ Latitude : Factor w/ 65 levels "06'19'365","06'21'050",..: 39 12 10 13 2 
6 4 3 5 21 ...
 $ Longitude: Factor w/ 65 levels "79'44'179","79'46'107",..: 16 52 58 65 64 
60 56 57 55 36 ...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, post the results of `str(targetCounts)`.

Comment: There it goes..

Comment: Try with `dms2deg(as.character(targetCounts$Longitude), sep = "'")`

Comment: Now it works, thank you so much. I still have the problem that the seconds must be less than 60, but the above error doesn´t appear.